# Unskippable Reward ads in flutter using admob

Tags: flutter, admob, firebase-admob

Is there a way to make a reward ad an unskippable ad in AdMob in flutter ??
I am using the firebase_admob library from google already but I still can skip reward ads!

Comment: As far as i know  Admob reward ads cannot be unskippable, Google does not allow it.

Comment: oh, then what about unity ads can I make it unskippable in my application! @stillKonfuzed

Comment: Yes, Unity rewarded ads are unskippable

Comment: Rewards ads are meant to be triggered by users for getting a reward, so that makes it skippable/cancelable even before the ads end. You can use other ad format like Interratical ads which provides some* videos ads that are not cancellable. @MohamedSalah